# With Perl, how do I use dbh csv_tables to read a CSV string from the standard input?

Tags: database, perl, csv

Below is an example of how to use dbh csv_tables to read a CSV file into a database. However I already have a CSV string that I want to use with dbh csv_tables. How would I read the string from the standard input instead of a file?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

# Connect to the database, (the directory containing our csv file(s))

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:CSV:f_dir=.;csv_eol=\n;");

# Associate our csv file with the table name 'prospects'

$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'prospects'} = { 'file' => 'prospects.csv'};

# Output the name and contact field from each row

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM prospects WHERE name LIKE 'G%'");
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    print("name = ", $row->{'Name'}, "  contact = ", $row->{'Contact'}. "\n");
}
$sth->finish();
```

Cheers

Liam

Comment: I think [DBD::AnyData](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-AnyData/) is a better match, see [Creating an in-memory table from Strings](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-AnyData/lib/DBD/AnyData.pm#Creating_an_in-memory_table_from_Strings) for example. I haven't used DBD::AnyData though.

Answer (score 1):

[DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aCSV) subclasses [DBD::File](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD%3a%3aFile), which in turn uses [IO::File](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aFile) for the CSV file handle. We can override the file opening behavior of DBD::CSV of setting `f_dontopen` to `true`, which prevents DBD::File from opening the file passed in by DBD::CSV.

```
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'prospects'} = { f_dontopen => 1 };
```

Then, we just need to provide our own `IO::File` object that points to standard input.

```
my $io = new IO::File;
$io->fdopen(fileno(STDIN),'r');
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'prospects'} = { fh => $io, f_dontopen => 1 };
```

Putting this all together:

```
# Connect to the database
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:CSV:;csv_eol=\n;");

# Associate stdin the table name 'prospects'
my $io = new IO::File;
$io->fdopen(fileno(STDIN),'r');
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'prospects'} = { fh => $io, f_dontopen => 1 };

# Output the name and contact field from each row
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM prospects WHERE name LIKE 'G%'");
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    print("name = ", $row->{'name'}, "  contact = ", $row->{'contact'}. "\n");
}
$sth->finish();
```